# Mocking class module in Jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

Hey having problems mocking http requests in jest:
That's my folder structure and files:

```
.
├── config
│   ├── __mocks__
│   │   └── api.js
│   └── api.js
├── handlers
│   ├── __tests__
│   │   └── getUser.js
│   └── getUser.js
```

*config/__mocks__/api.js*

```
const api = {
  get: (endpoint, config) =>
    new Promise(resolve => {
      resolve({ data: { type: 'test' } });
    }),
};
export default api;
```

*config/api.js*

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { SERVER } from './const';

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: SERVER.PROD,
  timeout: 10000,
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
  },
});

export default api;
```

*handlers/getUser.js*

```
import api from '../config/api';
import { ENDPOINT } from '../config/endpoints';
import {serverResponseExtractor, errorHandler}  from '../util';

const getUsers = params => {
  const result = api.get(ENDPOINT).then(
      serverResponseExtractor,
    ),
    errorHandler,
  );

  return result;
};

export default getUsers;
```

*handlers/__tests__/getUser-test.js*

```
import getVods from '../getUser';

jest.mock('api');

test('getUsers> Returns valid User object', async () => {
  const currentOutput = await getUser(params);

  expect(currentOutput).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

I'm basically trying to replace `api` on getUser with mocked version.
I'm struggling with it for a long time and I can't make the `getUser` to use mocked `api` instead.
The `currentOutput` always return actual api call instead of mocked response.

Is there something I'm missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a relative path in the call to jest.mock:

```
jest.mock('../../config/api');
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using jest.getMockFn(). The standard mock had problems with mocking an object.

```
import api from '../../../src/provider/config/api';
import getUser from '../../../src/provider/handler/getUser';

import { getUserMocks } from './_handlersMocks';

api.get = jest.genMockFn();
api.get.mockImplementation(
  (url, config) =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve({ data: { items: ['getUserMocks.apiResponseMock'] } });
    }),
);
test(...)
```